# Available updates not found in Drupal under WAMP environment

Tags: drupal, module, wamp

While our hosted websites work fine, I've had trouble with the "Available updates" page in Drupal when on a local PC under a WAMP environment.  No modules show.  If I use "Check manually", I get the following error:

```
Unable to fetch any information about available new releases and updates.
```

I'm able to browse drupal.org from the same PC.  The PC is on a network proxy server.

Any ideas on how to get this working so that we can test new/updated modules locally on the network PC?  I'm not quite sure if it's the network proxy, Drupal install, WAMP environment, or some other firewall issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when testing under WAMP,I found that it was a problem with our network proxy (which required authentication). As Drupal was making the update request 'in the background' the authentication wasn't being fulfilled and the proxy was denying access. In the end we had to reconfigure the network proxy

Comment: Thanks.  I should probably get in touch with our IT people to verify.  Does Drupal use port 80 on drupal.org to check for updates?

Comment: yep, its via http port (80), so your proxy will need to be open from your server to drupal.org (and ftp.drupal.org) port 80.